# Error with Google Sheets and Scripts and phone number with spaces (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a column with phone numbers.

Most of them have a "normal" format -> 999111999111

Then, I have some numbers in the format +65 999 222 999 222, and google sheets is returning "Formula parse error" and showing #ERROR! even if the value can be seen if you click on it.

I can fix it by manually deleting the spaces, but need to automate it.

When in google scripts I use .getvalue(), automatically get the #ERROR! string and can´t manipulate the string using regex.

Any idea how can I fix the error?

Comment: you can try `.getFormula()`, or add `'` in front of the value for it to not be treated as formula, or change the cell format to text before entering the value

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in Find & Replace feature activate the Use Regular Expressions checkboxes to replace all the starting `+` (the regular expression to use is `^\+`). It's opt to you to replace them by an empty string (just left the replace box empty) or replace it by `'+` in order to force that the cell value be parsed as text instead of a formula.

An alternative from the side of Apps Script is to use `getFormula` instead of `getValue`.

Comment: @I'-'I What makes you believe that?

Comment: @I'-'I I misread the that part of the question. Thank you for the feedback. Side note, sometimes Google Sheets automatically replace `+` by `=`, others treats value starting with `+` as plain text while others as a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Find `^`(start of line) and replace with`'`(denoting that the following is a string and not to be parsed)

Make sure to check "search using regex" and "inside formulas".

Comment: Issue is that I can´t even get the value of it

var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Testing-code'); 
var customerNumber= RegExp(ss.getRange(1,1).getValue())
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(customerNumber)}

I just get the error, and can´t use the find formula on it. Modifying one by one and adding the ' fix the issue, but can´t automate it

Comment: @Saul You don't need scripts. Just use inbuilt "Find and Replace"

Answer (score 0):

Just use find and replace and change =+ with '+

Comment: Please [edit] according to [answer] in order to make the additional insight more obvious which you contribute. As is, the post gives the impression of being a less detailed, less (or not at all) explained part of the solutions already provided in existing answers. Please also consider taking the [tour].