# Error with Phone Number Format in Goolge Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a google sheet with phone numbers that return "#ERROR" in the cell due to the format, causing the entry to be recognized as a formula, e.g. - "+1 123-456-0987". There's at least one other post detailing a similar error, but I've not been able to extrapolate a solution from that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51688092/error-with-google-sheets-and-scripts-and-phone-number-with-spaces-javascript)

I've created an App Script to find and replace the "=" with a "'" (single quote). Running this script has no affect on my sheet. I've modified the script to replace "+" with "" (blank value) to see if this would make a difference and it too has no affect.

Considering that there is something up with my find and replace values, I tested the script with basic text and that DOES work.

So, my question is, where am I going wrong in my script? Script is below for reference.

```
function findAndReplaceText() {
  const searchText = "=";
  const replaceText = "'";
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const rangeLoc = "A2:A10";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeLoc);

  range
  .createTextFinder(searchText)
  .replaceAllWith(replaceText)

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Tried replacing the find and replace values. I'm expecting for the phone numbers to be visible in the cell instead of an error.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me

Comment: @Cooper Thanks for confirming. This is odd then - my script is working for text, but not the phone number entries. The fact that it's working for plain text tells me I'm executing the script correctly so I'm not clear on where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question and showing script, I guessed that in your script, `matchFormulaText(true)` is required to be used. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function findAndReplaceText() {
  const searchText = "=";
  const replaceText = "'+"; // Modified
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const rangeLoc = "A2:A10";

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeLoc);

  range
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .matchFormulaText(true) // Added
    .replaceAllWith(replaceText);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [matchFormulaText(matchFormulaText)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#matchformulatextmatchformulatext)